# MAX of 3rd column evaluation when we try to isnumber search search of two columns - company name and risk code but i am not finding a way

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17cW-RFn1zqFMSeKSwPEqcZUlfz2W7lbv10DZXSrJy5w/edit?usp=sharing)[image]

You can refer the first table Evaluation report where details of the company names in column A and Risk Codes in Column B and similar evaluation results for all the companies are presented in column C.

I just need the formula to get the column c result max value of evaluation for the key XYZ Singapore/china/thailand.. etc., and cODE 210-abc301-bcda401-cdez..etc., which are static and already available in the template. Just need a formula to get the max evaluation rating for the key combinations mentioned in Result table Column A (COMPANY) & Column B (risk code).

Second Table- Result Table where the results are shown in this manually after checking the details manually in each column and which is difficult to do and not getting right results as well as too much of data in single-cell as we have 100's of company names and 1000's of risk codes and evaluation results for the same.

Is there a way i can find the max evaluation results of the each company and risk codes evaluation results in second table like shown in the impage with the red font.

Example:
xyz singapore is the company and for risk code 210 what is max evaluation which is 100% max(100%,75%,50%) and similarly for xyz china and 401 which is 100% -max(100%,90%,75%,50%)

I am able to find the separate formula to find each sell to get the details but not able to find it by using the entire columns and max value of evaluation. Hence anyof the experts can take few minutes and help with the formula.
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E4,A4)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F4,B4))),C4,0)

This one giving the result of each row whether it has values related to that cell or not but me want the
max evaluation value of the each company and risk code in the evaluation report.

If anything is not clear, please let me know.

Thanks for the help!

Regard
Suresh

Comment: a) I don't believe xyz singapore should return 90% in this example - i.e. there is no corresponding word singapore in cell A5 (only the code xyz in B5) and b) Including a google sheet template will go a long way to helping others reproduce your problem and thus solve rate/speed will increase drastically - now I have to go a recreate your screenshot myself which is a bother and so tempting to skip it in favour of others who have generously done so/such.  Despite these 'issues'/set-backs - will gladly attempt to solve your issue (or at least the one I believe you have).. ☺

Comment: Thanks, James added a google sheet with an example, please check it James if time permits:) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17cW-RFn1zqFMSeKSwPEqcZUlfz2W7lbv10DZXSrJy5w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I find your description of what you want for results unclear. Can you clarify, perhaps with a screenshot, **exactly** what you want for results, given the data that you have posted.

Comment: Reslut Table  
Company Code Evaluation (Max)
xyz singapore 210 100%
xyz singapore 301 0%
xyz singapore 401 75%

Comment: What is the criteria by which you are selecting only Singapore to show in the Result table?

Comment: Actually just shown singapore as an example similarly i need to find for all the company data. Its just reference data for many company:Company Code Evaluation (Max)
xyz singapore 210 100%
xyz singapore 301 0%
xyz singapore 401 75%
xyz Dubai 210 50%
xyz Dubai 301 0%
xyz Dubai 401 0%
xyz china 210 100%
xyz china 301 90%
xyz china 401 75%
xyz taipei 210 100%
xyz taipei 301 0%
xyz taipei 401 0%
xyz hong kong 210 100%
xyz hong kong 301 0%
xyz hong kong 401 0%
xyz seoul 210 100%
xyz seoul 301 0%
xyz seoul 401 0%

Comment: Hi - I requested access to your sheet above,  I've also updated the permission level so that anyone can edit.  See chat...

Answer (score 0):

### ♣ SOLVED ♣

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRBJK1sBnNV816E_LcQsNr2NSrTClQwS-uCxEl-RacWlWVckjliJ8YKtz-5fYxRtACsUAW-fbv1VS5w/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true) is the full result table:

**UPDATE**
[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aOiU5xHPMLuyo8v8zDyYLiJskzTydVfD/view?usp=sharing) is a second link that you can use to download the excel file itself = best of luck mate! (let me know if any other questions).

**Sheets | screenshot**

See [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bzbG68tUoJzVt_bCgqX1dJCavV37pFttOJiMcr37Ozg/edit?usp=sharing), per screenshot below:

---

[image: Country]

'ArrayFormula' function given in screenshot above should be removed (along with corresponding outer brackets when deploying in Excel)..

---

[image: Code (variant)]

(static in Google-Sheets with function for single cell G3 given below i.e. in G13)

---

[image: Max score]

(static in Google-Sheets with function for single cell H3 given below i.e. in H13)

**Equations**

(in corresponding order for respective screenshots above):

```
=INDEX(MID($A$3:$A$7,SEARCH(" ",$A$3:$A$7)+1,SEARCH("|",$A$3:$A$7)-SEARCH(" ",$A$3:$A$7)-1),0)
=SORTBY(FILTER($B$3:$B$7,1*(1*IFERROR(MATCH("*"&$A$3:$A$7&"*",$A$3:$A$76,0)/MATCH("*"&$A$3:$A$7&"*",$A$3:$A$76,0),)=1)),FILTER($C$3:$C$7,1*(1*IFERROR(MATCH("*"&$F$3:$F$7&"*",$A$3:$A$76,0)/MATCH("*"&$F$3:$F$7&"*",$A$3:$A$7,0),)=1)),-1)
=INDEX($C$3:$C$7,MATCH(G3#,$B$3:$B$7,0))
```

Comment: Can you please share the google sheet which you prepared as I am not clear which formulas were to be used.... if you can share the google sheet which was prepared can be helpful.. thanks James:)

Comment: i am trying using the formula not getting correct results and me just want one column to get the result which is Column C as Column A & B already available in the template which is a static one. So based on company name and risk code combination get the max evaluation rating in column c of the result table.

Comment: RE: link - If you click the link in the first paragraph - the word 'here' - very first line - you'll be taken there - how could you miss that btw [unless it's not working?])

Comment: Can you open the link- the formula work fine (assuming you have Office 365?)

Comment: Have updated my soln to now reference a 2nd link as well - the excel file via Google Drive.  After you select the link select the option to download - once downloaded, you can open in Excel and see exact same thing my screenshot(s) show - i.e. you'll see the respective equations in the function bar and you'll see how this work (I've double checked)

Comment: i have office 2013 installed in my laptop and still getting the same error message when I tried to access it..requested access again.  google-sureshraichur84. I am looking for last evaluation column result only will also will do for me as rest two can be static every month only evaluation rating will be changed every month and the same i need the formula. to find the max evaluation value for the each of the combinations listed in A & B columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232136/discussion-between-suresh7860-and-james).